# Rails 3 - Sign Responses with HMAC-SHA256

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sha256, hmacsha1

I am using OpenSSL HMAC SHA256 method to sign all my requests to the server generating a HASH using a private key. My requests look like:
www.myserver.com/url/to/resource?par1=val1&par2=val2&par3=val3&hash=GENERATEDHASH

So my server calculates a hash using the parameters and the same key, if the hashes match he considers that the request is OK.

I want to sign the responses (using a HTTP header maybe) too. My idea is to calculate the hash  using the content of the response and add that hash to the header, so my other side can validate that response before processing it.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I'm looking to calculate an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC with the SHA256 hash algorithm using a string and a secret key.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to emulate Amazon's way of doing it?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html